# How to acess Inner Wrapper List

Tags: apex, rest-api

```
public with sharing class Wrapperclass {

    public  List<String> destination_addresses{get;set;}
    public  List<String> origin_addresses{get;set;}
    public  List<Rows> rows{get;set;}
    public  String status{get;set;}

    public class Rows {
        public List<Elements> elements{get;set;}
    }

    public class Elements {
        public Distance distance{get;set;}
        public Distance duration{get;set;}
        public String status{get;set;}
    }

    public class Distance {
        public String text{get;set;}
        public Integer value{get;set;}
    }
}
```

deserialized json using this code and my wrapper is as above I want to acess Value of text inside Distance.

```
Type resultType = Type.forName('Wrapperclass');
Wrapperclass deserializeResults =(Wrapperclass)JSON.deserialize(resp.getBody(),resultType);
```

Comment: Where are you stuck at? You need to loop through your wrapper to get down.. Well actually to be fair you could just do `deserializeResults.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access it like you would any other standard object, you can just do `deserializeResults.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text` but I doubt that is the outcome you want

```
Wrapperclass deserializeResults =(Wrapperclass)JSON.deserialize(resp.getBody(),resultType);

for(Rows wc : deserializeResults.rows)
{
    for(Elements ele : wc.elements)
    {
        System.debug('ele ' + ele.distance.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Outer class prefix if code not inside `Wrapperclass`?